# Prevent MouseArea from catching clicks within child rect

Tags: qt, qml, touch-event, rectangles, mousearea

I have a fullscreen map, on which I added a mouse area:

```
   Map {
      id: map
      anchors.fill: parent
      plugin: osm
      zoomLevel: 16
      minimumZoomLevel: 13
      maximumZoomLevel: 20

      gesture.enabled: true

      Rectangle {
         id: infoPanel
         // ...

         Button {
            // ...
         }
      }

      MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onPressed: {
               infoPanel.visible = false
         }
      }
```

The `infoPanel` rect will ocasionally be made visible, overlaying the map with some information, and a button to trigger a certain action.

Now I have added the mouse area to the map in order to hide the info panel whenever the map is clicked, which works fine.

However, the info panel is also dismissed when the rectangle of the info panel itself is clicked.

How can I prevent the mouse area from the map to interfere with anything which is inside `infoPanel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to way:

1. you must set *z* value of info panel to *map.z + 1* and define mouse area for info panel to capture mouse event. like below code

   ```
   Map {
       id: map
       anchors.fill: parent
       plugin: osm
       zoomLevel: 16
       minimumZoomLevel: 13
       maximumZoomLevel: 20
       gesture.enabled: true

   Rectangle {
       id: infoPanel
       width: 100
       height: 100
       color: "red"
       z: map.z + 1

       MouseArea {
           anchors.fill: parent

           onClicked: {
               print("info panel")
           }
       }

       Button {
           width: parent.width / 2
           height: width
           anchors.centerIn: parent
           text: "button"

           onClicked: {
               print("button")
           }
       }
   }

   MouseArea {
       anchors.fill: parent

       onPressed: {
           infoPanel.visible = false
           print("map")
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. or just move your mouse area to up of info panel

   ```
       Map {
       id: map
       anchors.fill: parent
       plugin: osm
       zoomLevel: 16
       minimumZoomLevel: 13
       maximumZoomLevel: 20
       gesture.enabled: true

   MouseArea {
       anchors.fill: parent

       onPressed: {
           infoPanel.visible = false
           print("map")

       }
   }

   Rectangle {
       id: infoPanel
       width: 100
       height: 100
       color: "red"

       MouseArea {
           anchors.fill: parent

           onClicked: {
               print("info panel")
           }
       }

       Button {
           width: parent.width / 2
           height: width
           anchors.centerIn: parent
           text: "button"


           onClicked: {
               print("button")

           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks, solution 1 worked. I tried the same yesterday, but it didn't work because I put the `MouseArea` within the info panel after the `Button` in the QML, which made the button no longer work.
I didn't know that the order of elements in QML mattered, so with the `MouseArea` first it now works.